# Doctrine: Update whole Entity

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, cascade

first off some code:

```
class User {
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $profiles;
}
```

(There's come more code, but this is the part affecting my problem).

So for example I have

Already in Database

```
User1: id = 1
Profile1: id = 1, parent = User1
Profile2: id = 2, parent = User2
```

Not yet persisted

```
Profile3: 
Profile4:
```

What I want to do is to be able to just call:

```
$user1->removeAllProfiles(); $user1->addAllNewProfiles(array($profile3, $profile4));
```

and this should automatically delete all the old profiles and add all the new.

I hope it's clear what I want to achieve. Anyone having an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your property annotation to make use of `orphanRemoval`...

```
/** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true) */
protected $profiles;
```

This tells Doctrine to remove any profiles that are left without an associated `User` object, so when you call `$user->removeAllProfiles();` and then call `$em->flush()` any previous `Profile` objects associated with the user will be removed from the database.